# Cannot get cron.service status using systemctl

Tags: 15.04, cron, systemd

I noticed my cronjobs were running at the incorrect times, so I changed my time zone.  I now need to restart the cron daemon, but none of the commands I'm using are working for me.  Every one of them results in a time-out:

```
root@localhost:~# systemctl restart cron.service
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to restart cron.service: Connection timed out

root@localhost:~# systemctl status cron.service
Failed to get properties: Connection timed out
```

I can see the cron.service file in /lib/systemd/system/:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234 Oct 27  2014 cron.service
```

I'm using Ubuntu Server 15.04 x64.

---

Update: Rebooted the server, now I can't start any systemd unit (mysql, nginx, whatever)

Answer (score 2):

It is a [known bug with `policykit-1`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/1447654/).

The solution is to run:

```
sudo apt-get purge policykit-1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo systemctl reboot
```

This issue started after I tried to install the `firewalld` package.